# Google Books API Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, google-books

With this demo I get rate limit exceeded from the Google Books API:

https://angular-temp-slice-demo.stackblitz.io/books

To see it open the developer console in chrome and then do some searches.  The rate limit errors will show in the console.

```
[],"lazyUpdate":null},"status":403,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test: 403 OK","error":{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"userRateLimitExceededUnreg","message":"User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up","extendedHelp":"https://code.google.com/apis/console"}],"code":403,"message":"User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"}}}
```

This is the search code [(And a link to the stackblitz book.service)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-temp-slice-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fbook.service.ts):

```
  onSearch(query: string) {
    this.bookStore.query = query;
    this.query$.pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(async (query: string) => {
          const bo: Observable<Book[]> = this.searchAPI(query);
          const books: Book[] = await bo.toPromise();
          this.bookStore.reset();
          this.bookStore.postA(books);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

However this Akita demo does not get this:

https://akita-books-store.stackblitz.io/#/books/find

Anyone know what's causing the rate limit exceeded error?  I have set debounce time to 500 milliseconds.

Comment: *I have set debounce time to 500 milliseconds.* - looks like you did it wrong, if you look in the console, there's definitely more than two requests per second - of course, you've shared no code so ...

Comment: All the code is in the stackblitz ...

Comment: Also added the `onSearch` function to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.bookStore.observeQuery().pipe(filter(Boolean),
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(async (query: string) => {
          const bo: Observable<Book[]> = this.searchAPI(query);
          const books: Book[] = await bo.toPromise();
          this.bookStore.reset();
          this.bookStore.postA(books);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Before I was doing the above code block inside of `onSearch` and it causes to a subscription to be created each time the `onSearch` triggered.  Now the only thing in `onSearch` is this:

```
  onSearch(query: string) {
    this.bookStore.query = query;
  }
```